# Combine many notifications to one

Tags: php, mysql, select, group-by

I'm re-creating my notification system to make it able to combine many notifications to one. Instead of showing 9 rows that say "Adam has answered your question", it could say "9 people have answered your question".

My current notification table looks like this:

```
notification_id (PK) | recipient_id | sender_id | type | foreign_id | date | viewed
```

Recipient_id is the one to get the notification. Sender_id is the one it came from. Type is what kind of notification, so I know what it should say, "xx has answered" or "xx liked your post". Foreign_id could be the ID of a question.

Which would be the best way to create this "combine" system? Should I update the notification when there is a new answer and say that another person has answered too, or should the query maybe count how many there is of the same foreign_id. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT foreign_id, SUM(IF (TYPE= 'like', 1, 0)) likecnt, 
       SUM(IF(TYPE = 'answer', 1, 0)) anscnt 
FROM notification 
GROUP BY foreign_id
```

**EDIT: Check this**

```
SELECT n.foreign_id, n.sender_id
FROM notifications n 
INNER JOIN (SELECT foreign_id, MAX(DATE) DATE 
            FROM notifications 
            GROUP BY foreign_id, user_id
           )  a ON n.foreign_id = a.foreign_id AND n.date = a.date
```

Comment: Awesome! SELECT foreign_id, sender_id FROM notifications GROUP BY foreign_id, user_id This combines many rows to one, how do I get the latest row when grouping? I want the latest sender_id for each grouping so I want to get sender_id from the row with highest notification_id. (Hope you understand.)

Comment: @lawls check my updated answer to find the solution of your last query.